# Make a jQuery datepicker display two years when selected

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

My datepicker needs to represent the current financial year (i.e it should display *2014/2015*, *2015/2016*, etc) when the calendar has been selected.

My datepicker below displays "*2015/2015*", but I need the first year to be the year before. Is there a way to do this?

```
$("#datepicker1").datepicker({
    dateFormat : "yy/yy", 
    viewMode   : "years", 
    changeYear : true
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if the datepicker has any method for that, but there's a little workaround using [`onSelect`](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-onSelect):

```
$("#datepicker1").datepicker({
    dateFormat : "yy",
    viewMode   : "years", 
    changeYear : true,
    onSelect   : function(d){
        $(this).val((parseInt(d)-1)+'/'+d);
    }
});
```

**[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9o5e13uu/)**

Comment: Brilliant!! Works exactly as I need it to, thank you Artur!!! P.S the jsfiddle didn't work for me but when I implemented it into my code it works 100%